# Determine the probability that they will defeat Chicago and Indiana.

Tags: probability

I honestly have no idea how to approach this question, i was thinking that it would help if i used fractions instead of percentage... but it wouldn't change anything... i don't know what to do.

The Toronto Raptors have a 30% chance of winning if they lose the previous game and a 60% chance of winning they it win the previous game. At the start of the season they have a 65% chance of winning their first game.

They play Chicago, New York, then Indiana to start the season. Determine the probability that they will defeat Chicago and Indiana.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the array:

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|}
&\text{Chicago}&\text{New York}&\text{Indiana}\\\hline
1&W&W&W\\
2&W&W&L\\
3&W&L&W\\
4&W&L&L\\
5&L&W&W\\
6&L&W&L\\
7&L&L&W\\
8&L&L&L\\\hline
\end{array}$$

Each row represents a win-loss scenario. We are interested in the probability of rows $1$ and $3$, that is, rows where Chicago and Indiana are defeated.

We have that $\mathbb{P}(\text{Row $1$})$ is:

$$\mathbb{P}(\text{Chicago$=W$})\cdot\mathbb{P}(\text{New York$=W$}|\text{Chicago$=W$})\cdot\mathbb{P}(\text{Indiana$=W$}|\text{New York$=W$})\\
=0.65\cdot0.6\cdot0.6=0.234=23.4\%$$

We have that $\mathbb{P}(\text{Row $3$})$ is:

$$\mathbb{P}(\text{Chicago$=W$})\cdot\mathbb{P}(\text{New York$=L$}|\text{Chicago$=W$})\cdot\mathbb{P}(\text{Indiana$=W$}|\text{New York$=L$})\\
=0.65\cdot(1-0.6)\cdot0.3=0.078=7.8\%$$

Finally, the probability that either row $1$ or row $3$ occur is the sum of the probability of each of them, because they are mutually exclusive. The answer is hence $31.2\%$.

Comment: so I'm still a little bit confused, what did you do to get 0.65?

Comment: oh never mind its already in the question lol, i was over thinking it. But thank you this helped a lot!

Comment: Glad to have helped!